# Работа с массивами Java

Tags: java

Есть несколько объектов, у каждого по 4 переменных, для которых созданы геттеры и сеттеры. Значение этих переменных пользователь вводит с клавиатуры. 
 Как занести введенные данные в массив, если они могут быть как строковые, так и числовые?

То есть я понимаю, что можно использовать метод `toString();` и занести все в массив типа `String[]`, но как дальше работать этим массивом? Если, к примеру, понадобится какое-то числовое значение, а для занесения в массив я его сделал строковым, как его заново преобразовать? 
 Или есть какой-то более изящный способ? Подскажите пжлст

Comment: Только что был похожий вопрос, почитайте, может покажется полезным: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709147/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2/709179#709179

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt(String s)`

то же самое с `float` и `double`